# Method signature template in Import library

Tags: script#

I am working on an Script# import library and I have the following issue.

This is the javascript output I want,

```
o.addListener('resize', resizeHandler);
```

and in the import library this method looks like

```
[ScriptName("addListener")]
public void AddListenerResize(string eventname, ResizeEventHandler callback)
{
...
}
```

I wish I could achieve this with an attribute like this,

```
[ScriptNameTemplate("addListener('resize',{0})")]
public void AddListenerResize(ResizeEventHandler callback)
{
...
}
```

Because the first parameter is a constant and redundant and I dont want to be expose to a typing error.

The concrete question is about how would you achieve that with the available tools.

Any advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Script# supports such a feature.

Why don't you wrap the raw imported API into a more convinient one:

```
public class RawAPI
{
  [ScriptName("addListener")]
  public void AddListener(string eventname, ResizeEventHandler callback)
  {
  ...
  }
}

public class GoodAPI
{
  readonly RawAPI _RawAPI;      

  public void AddListenerResize(ResizeEventHandler callback)
  {
    _RawAPI.AddListener("resize", callback);
  }
}
```

Then, use only `GoodAPI` and forget about the typos. I'd even try making the `RawAPI` internal, but it may be technically impossible for an import library method.

Comment: I've considered doing something similar to what you sudgest. I just wanted to know if is there a short way to do it. The problem is that I have an exclusive Import project to wrap the Api. So I cannot have a script method inside. A partial solution is to create an enum marked with the NameValue attribute. But its just half the solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion is to create a named-values enum representing the valid string values for event name.

Example:

```
[Imported]
[NamedValues]
public enum Events {

    Resize = 0
}
```

And then have your API take in an Events parameter, rather than a string eventName parameter.

Comment: I like this trick. Thanks. I is a good way to minimize typos to have an enum with all the event names. But if I want to completelly avoid them I should have one enum for each event type and each enum with just one member (the event name).